# What is the easiest way of executing a series of T-SQL scripts sequentially without the command prompt?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am not allowed to use command prompt, unfortunately.

Currently I use SQL Server Management Studio, but I could switch to VS2010, if it was easier there.

Running a set of scripts in a specific order, especially when doen manually, is a bit tedious.

Thank you very much for any suggestions you might have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [edit and run SQL scripts in SSMS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx) if this helps

You can use `:r filename.sql` command in the SQLCMD script command to execute a sql script

```
:r first.sql
:r second.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to create a job with no schedule, then you can run it manually.
Each step in the job could be one of your scripts.

The benefit of using a job would be that you could set up alerting and get an email if any step failed.